# VLC does not play video.

Tags: drivers, video

I know this might sound silly, but how the heck do you get VLC to play a movie? I hear the sound but I have a black screen. Is there any other media player like Kmplayer or Gump? I’m at my wit’s end here!

Answer (score 0):

Try installing Ubuntu Restricted Extras from the Software Center if you haven't already. Also, please don't post a questions with undescriptive titles like that and try to give more details. File format, for example, would be useful.

Comment: avi, mp4, vob, etc...

Comment: Did you install what I told you to?

Comment: does not solve the problem